# Microsoft Teams remember status message based on network

Tags: microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

In Skype for business, if you are working from home you could set your status to "Working from Home" and Everytime you reconnect to that same network Skype for business will remember your status from last time you were on that network so you don't have to set it again. How can you do that in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: Please follow this documentation [Change your status](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-your-status-in-teams-ce36ed14-6bc9-4775-a33e-6629ba4ff78e) for set status message in Teams.

Comment: That is for the status, but not the status message. I know you can set the status message in that same area, but that is setting it for a fixed duration, not based on the currently connected network.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch more digging I found that it is not the status message in Skype for Business but the location I was thinking of, and it would appear that is not in Teams and at the moment is not even on the roadmap.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-AMA/Set-your-location-in-Microsoft-Teams/m-p/120555

There is a uservoice where people are requesting this but it is only under review.
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33331429-my-location